# Can you still travel to a Schengen country on a Schengen visa, even if your UAE residence visa is expiring next month?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, uae, malta

I'm planning to travel to Europe (Malta) for a few days this coming Eid holidays. I still have a valid Schengen visa (valid until next month), but my UAE Residence Visa is expiring next month. I hold a Philippine passport. Just wondering if this will be an issue.

Comment: What passport do you have?

Comment: Philippine passport...

Comment: Which city in the UAE do you live/work in?

Comment: So you're wondering if it'll be a problem on your return to the UAE?

Comment: Leave and enter, I know you can't travel if your passport is less than 6 months I'm not sure if the residence visa would be an issue as well as mine would be expiring next month.

Comment: Somewhat related question (with no definitive answer unfortunately): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21929/i-have-a-schengen-visa-but-my-uae-residence-visa-cancelled-can-i-still-travel-t

Answer (score 5):

Once you have a visa, the rules regarding entry in the Schengen area are laid out in the [Schengen Borders Code](http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/justice_freedom_security/free_movement_of_persons_asylum_immigration/l14514_en.htm) ([Regulation 562/2006](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32006R0562:EN:NOT)). The relevant part is article 5 (that's the consolidated version, this was added recently):

> (a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border satisfying the following criteria:
>
> (i) its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended date of departure from the territory of the Member States. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>
> (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;

So your *passport* must be valid for at least three months after your intended *departure* date. There are a few other conditions but nothing that suggests that the UAE visa/residence permit would be an issue. On the UAE side, if it's like in (the countries I know in) Europe, you could probably reenter the country until the last day of validity of your residence permit but I really don't know.

Comment: _"you could probably reenter the country until the last day of validity of your residence permit"_ - yup you can.