# I have a Schengen visa but my UAE Residence visa cancelled. Can I still travel then?

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, uae

I'm a Philippine passport holder.  I have applied recently for a Schengen and UK visa and was approved.  Unfortunately before my travel dates came my UAE residence needs to be cancelled as I was terminated.

Can I still travel to Europe since I have a visa with them and be back to UAE on a visit visa.  Will all these be possible to do?

Comment: what i understand: 1. you are currently at UAE, 2. You gonna visit Europe, 3. planning to take UAE visa there, 4. travel back to UAE (& all along u are holding Filipino passport).
is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't quite understand. Where do you currently live at the moment? You said you will come back to UAE on a visit visa, have you obtained it already? Basically, you can travel to EU and UK if you have valid visas. That won't be a problem if they believe that you will return to your home country before your visa expires. You might have to be ready to prove that you won't stay in EU area longer than your visa. They might ask for your return ticket at the border.

Comment: I guess an issue could be that the person applied as a UAE resident with a job there, providing some assurance that they have strong incentives to go back and would now show up at the border with no job and no right to return to the UAE permanently, which does not look as good from the perspective of the border guard. But I do not know whether they would typically ask about that at the border (by contrast, sufficient means and purpose of the stay can definitely be checked once more).