# Can I travel to UK as tourist even my UAE residence visa was cancelled?

Tags: visas, uk, uae

My UAE residence visa will be cancelled next month and my UK tourist visa will expire end of March.  I am planning to go and have an exit to UK and will wait for my tourist visa going back to UAE when I am in UK.  Is that possible? Will immigration let me enter UK since my UK tourist visa isn't expired yet?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  will you leave before your visa expires?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not returning to your home country to wait for the new UAE visa?

Comment: Even better question Will UAE let you apply in the UK for a tourist visa if you're not a resident.

Comment: @Karlson The point is that the person already has a UK visa…

Comment: @Annoyed My second question wasn't about the UK visa and the first wasn't about whether or not the person has a UK visa.

Comment: Related question (but for a different destination): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21929/i-have-a-schengen-visa-but-my-uae-residence-visa-cancelled-can-i-still-travel-t?rq=1

Comment: @Karlson Indeed, I misread your comment. Still, it's not the question being asked.

Comment: @Annoyed No it is not but it is sort of important for the answer.

Comment: @Karlson I don't see why. Upon reading it again, it's true that what the OP intends to do with respect to the UAE is not entirely clear but the question being asked is whether he or she can enter the UK.

Comment: @Annoyed Because mentioning that *UK tourist visa isn't expired yet* normally would imply short time to exipiration.  So if the OP doesn't have a proof of onward travel and short time to expiration of visa he may be denied entry at UK border or he may be denied boarding the plane to UK by the airline, so this clarification can be important.

Comment: @Karlson All this indeed seems important and would probably be part of a good answer but isn't it wholly independent from UAE visa policy?

Comment: @Annoyed Ordinarily I'd agree with you.  However, OP makes it a point of getting UAE tourist visa while in the UK, which would imply an intended exit back to the UAE, so UAE policy and UK intended exit route became important.